# How to remove the Square Bracket in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

Below code is the returned JSON

```
[{"one":"id","two":"id","three":"id"},{"one":"id","two":"id","three":"id"}]
```

Below code is the desired result of the returned JSON (without the array bracket)

```
{"one":"id","two":"id","three":"id"},{"one":"id","two":"id","three":"id"}
```

Below code is to convert the array to the JSON format

```
include('connect-db.php'); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patientvaccinedetail"); 
$specific = []; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo '<td width="100px">' . $row['id'] . '</td>'; 
echo '<td width="200px">' . $row['patientid'] . '</td>'; 
echo '<td width="200px">' . $row['vaccineid'] . '</td>'; 
  //**********Convert the array into json******************* 

  $specific[] = ["one" => $row["id"],
                 "two" => $row["patientid"],
                 "three" => $row["vaccineid"]];

$result = json_encode($specific,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo $result;
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

To send the request to the API, iam using Guzzle
And the format the API require is {xx:xx},{xx:xx}
without the square bracket, any idea how to remove it using PHP.
Thanks in advance

```
     $client = new Client([
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                  'Token' => $token]
                           ]);

       $response = $client->post('http://localhost:91/Religious',
       ['body' => ***Where the json will be place***]
       );
```

Comment: Uhm… `trim($json, '[]')`…? But really, assuming the remote API wants actual JSON, this makes no sense.

Comment: I am aware of that, it's just the API require format like {xx}:{xx},{xx}:{xx}

Comment: So it doesn't want JSON, then.

Comment: Request body formats

application/json, text/json
Sample:
{
  "religious": "sample string 1",
  "religiousLang2": "sample string 2",
  "religiousLang3": "sample string 3"
}

Comment: If that's the format, then it does want JSON, and you're just confused about how to pass it. It wants a single object; you shouldn't be passing two.

Comment: How do you take from that sample that you can pass two objects separated by a comma…?

Comment: @cHao I've checked it, more than 1 object can be passed

Comment: So the API is asking for an Object.  Not an array. [] denotes an array while {} is an object.  The API is asking for an array of objects.   You need to create an object that implements \JsonSerializable and create a jsonSerialize() function which describes how to serialize your object.  ie.  return get_object_vars($this);

Answer (score 15):

I read a nice solution in the comments of the first post by [deceze ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) with `trim()`.

```php
$yourJson = trim($yourJson, '[]');
```

You can also use regular expression:

```php
// if nothing is found, your json has already no brackets or is invalid.
if (preg_match('/^\[(.+)\]$/', $yourJson, $new))
{
    /**
     * $new[0] = $yourJson
     * $new[1] = what's in the parenthesis
     */
    $yourJson = $new[1];
}
```

Or, you may use `substr()`:

```php
$yourJson = substr($yourJson, 1, strlen($yourJson) - 2);
```

**EDIT:**
When it says in the request body format : `application/json`, I do not think that you have to remove the brackets. Did you even try with them?

Comment: yes, i did, it only work when there's no square bracket

Comment: Using trim () works, thanks, still fails to send the data to the API for some reason

Comment: @Codezzz: Maybe because you're wrong about the format. Are there docs online for this API you're talking about? Cause it's quite rare to require semi-JSON and call it JSON.

Comment: @Codezzz: try `$client->post('http://localhost:91/Religious', ['json' =>$json ] );`. I replaced `body` by `json`. The `$json` variable has to be an array. Seen there : http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#uploading-data

Comment: @iArcadia: if you use `json`, looks like you're expected to pass the actual array, not a JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert a PHP array to a JSON array, so php wrap the result in brackets, it's totally normal. If you need a JSON object Then I would suggest to use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as additional option(parameters) in json_encode.

```
$object = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the implode function after a json decode. for example:

> implode(',',json_decode($text_from_db or $array))

for example $text_from_db=["rice","beans"]

the result will be- rice,beans

Answer (score 1):

you can trimit see example below 
trim($data, '[]')

Comment: or you can do it better like this:
json_decode(trim($address_pa, '[]'),true);

Answer (score 0):

I've added comments as to what the OP is trying to do. But here's my solution for future visitors of this question.

```
class Thing implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private $name;
    private $description;
    private $code;

    /**
     * Get the value of name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of name
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of description
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of description
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of code
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of code
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $vars = get_object_vars($this);

        return $vars;
    }
}

$thing = new Thing();
$thing->setName('Name');
$thing->setDescription('Description');
$thing->setCode('Code');

$results['items'] = [
    'thing1' => $thing,
    'thing2' => $thing
];

echo json_encode($results);
```

Here's the output

```
{
    "items": {
        "thing1": {
            "name": "Name",
            "description": "Description",
            "code": "Code"
        },
        "thing2": {
            "name": "Name",
            "description": "Description",
            "code": "Code"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the outer wrapper without disturbing any inner wrappers:

```
$wrapped = <<<EOD
[{"one":"id","two":"id","three":"id"},{"one":"id","two":"id","three":"id"}]
EOD;

$array = json_decode($wrapped, true);
$unwrapped = json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

print_r($unwrapped);
// {"0":{"one":"id","two":"id","three":"id"},"1":{"one":"id","two":"id","three":"id"}}
```

Comment: In a multi-level array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT will encode ALL nested numeric arrays as objects.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to use JSON string and perform String operations to remove all those not required characters.

Reason for doing this, the required output is not a valid JSON and won't be accepted by API. As you need it however, I would suggest you to convert the array into json using `json_encode` and then perform string operations to convert it into your desired output.

Comment: Why Downvote buddy? I have told you to use string operations and trim is one of them :P

Comment: Not my downvote, but "perform string operations" is devoid of actual details.